# Windows "Internet Time" can't reach time server, but w32tm can

Tags: networking, windows-10, ntp

This is a very strange problem: I can't synchronize time using the Windows Internet Time dialog, because I get a "Peer is unreachable" or timeout error. Temporarily disabling the firewall doesn't help. However, the w32tm command has no problem reaching the time server.

I have this problem on 2 computers on the same network (connected to the router via a wireless link consisting of 2 Ubiquiti Nanostations), but not on my laptop which is on a different network.

What could be the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: I assume that the downvote means that the answer is embarrassingly obvious to the downvoter. If so, perhaps the downvoter could impress us all by sharing his/her superior insights?

Comment: The Serial SU Downvoter strikes again... here, have my +1 to balance out

Answer (score 0):

So if it works through w32tm, why not just setting the time server there with:

w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"time.windows.com" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update

Have you tried other ntp servers, like e.g. 0.pool.ntp.org ?